# PHP Recursive data

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, recursive-query

Good day,
I hope somebody can help me with this...

I am working on a system where you capture and load test codes, some of the test codes can be group codes and the group codes can contain group codes as well.. I need to be able to load all the codes from groups and sub groups.

```
[Test Code] [isGroup] [groupCodes]
TEST         Yes       Code1,Code2,Code3
Code1        No
Code2        Yes       Code4,Code5
Code3        No
Code4        No
Code5        No
```

I have been trying several options and a few of them I have gone into infinite loops.

Here is the code I am currently using but this does not get the sub groups

```
function get_group_test_codes($mysqli, $testcode){
    $test_codes = array();
    $test_data = get_test_by_code($mysqli, $testcode);

    if(empty($test_data)){
        return $test_codes;
    }

    if($test_data["isgroup"]==1){
        $group_codes = explode(",",$test_data["groupcodes"]);
        foreach($group_codes as $group_code){
            $test_codes[] = $group_code;
        }
    } else {
        $test_codes[] = $testcode;    
    }
    return $test_codes;
}

function get_test_by_code($mysqli, $testcode){
    $data = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `testtypes` where `testcode` = '{$testcode}' limit 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $data = $row;
    }
    $result->free();
    return $data;
}
```

Expected result should be the following

```
array('Code1', 'Code3', 'Code4', 'Code5');
```

Code2 is excluded cause its a group code and only its group codes should be loaded

Comment: Can you tell what is your expected output? if I pass in TEST, should i get an array like `array('TEST', 'Code1', 'Code2', 'Code3')` ?

Comment: I would like it to return the following array('Code1', 'Code3', 'Code4', 'Code5')

Comment: What leads to excluding Code2?

Comment: The user inputs the code "TEST" so it see that it shows up as a group test, so it has to load those group codes but those codes could also be group tests and only their tests codes should be loaded

Comment: Here is a version that uses an array the emulates the database table and read. Rather more recursive test data. [Demonstration at eval.in](https://eval.in/535009). I will convert the code to use to use the database if required but you already have done that. Answer posted soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requirements:

- Given a 'TEST' code entry stored in a `list of entries` that may contain 'recursive groups of 'codes'...
- Return a list of all the 'TestCode' that are members of the 'group' but are not themselves a 'group'.

According to the OP, the codes are stored in a database. However, the entries are read one 'testcode' at a time by 'testCode'. To make my life easier, I setup an array the emulated the database table and provided a function `readTestCode($testCode)` that can be easily changed to read the database instead of the array.

Processing:

Given a `testCode`:

- if a 'group' then process each code in it and 'recurse around the list' as required.
- Otherwise output the `testcode'.

#### The code:

```
/** ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Given a TestCode - chase it down all the paths...
 *
 * @param string $testCode
 * @param array  $outCodes -- cummulative arrat - be reference
 */
function processOneTestCode($testCode, &$outCodes)
{
    $curCode = readTestCode($testCode); // get the details for this code
    if ($curCode['isGroup']) { // process all the records in the group
       foreach ($curCode['groupCode'] as $newCode) {
          processOneTestCode($newCode, $outCodes);
       }
    }
    else {
        $outCodes[] = $testCode; // add it to the output
    }
}
```

*Read the `testCode details`*

expand the groups into a list of `testcode` for ease of processing...

```
/** -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * This will be reading  one row of the database by TestCode
 * This version emulates the database read - accurately I expect! ;)
 *
 * @global array $dbTestCodes
 * @param string $testCode
 *
 * @return array (isGroup => bool, groupCode = array())
 */
function readTestCode($testCode)
{
    global $dbTestCodes; // lose this when using a database.

    $details = array();

    // put the database read here...

    if (isset($dbTestCodes[$testCode])) {
        $details = $dbTestCodes[$testCode];

        if ($details['isGroup']) { // explode the codes so we can  process them easily
            $codesList = explode(',', $details['groupCode']);
            $details['groupCode'] = $codesList;
        }
    }

    return $details;
}
```

#### Run it:

```
$outArray = array();  // output in here

/**
 *  process the one TestCode...
 */
processOneTestCode('TEST', $outArray);

/**
 *  the processOneTestCode function doesn't do any checks for duplicates...
 *
 *  So we need to remove duplicates and sort it so we can check it easily
 */
$outArray = array_unique($outArray);
sort($outArray);

// show it
echo '<pre>';
print_r($outArray);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

#### Test Data

```
/**
 * This is exactly how the database looks when you read it by `testCode`.
 */
$dbTestCodes = array(
    'TEST' => array('isGroup' => 1, 'groupCode' => 'CodeC,Code1,CodeB,Code2,Code3'),

    'Code1' => array('isGroup' => 0, 'groupCode' => ''),
    'Code2' => array('isGroup' => 1, 'groupCode' => 'Code4,Code5'),
    'Code3' => array('isGroup' => 0, 'groupCode' => ''),
    'Code4' => array('isGroup' => 0, 'groupCode' => ''),
    'Code5' => array('isGroup' => 0, 'groupCode' => ''),
    'CodeA' => array('isGroup' => 0, 'groupCode' => ''),
    'CodeB' => array('isGroup' => 1, 'groupCode' => 'CodeA,CodeD,Code2'),
    'CodeC' => array('isGroup' => 0, 'groupCode' => ''),
    'CodeD' => array('isGroup' => 0, 'groupCode' => ''),
);
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Code1
    [1] => Code3
    [2] => Code4
    [3] => Code5
    [4] => CodeA
    [5] => CodeC
    [6] => CodeD
)
```